# cancan authorization in unmatched model and controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

I am using cancan but i get slight problem..

```
my ability.rb
can :manage, Department
can :manage, Review
```

I have 2 cases it works for  case 1 but unfortunately not for case 2

```
case 1
```

my department controller

```
 load_and_authorize_resource :message => "Unable to read this article."
  Here it works because in this controller 
  I use model Department
```

Now my Reviews controller

```
 case 2



  class ReviewsController < ApplicationController


  load_and_authorize_resource :message => "Unable to read this article."
  layout 'system'
  respond_to :html, :json
  add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_url
  add_breadcrumb "Reviews", :reviews_path
  def index
   @page_title = "Reviews List"
    @reviews = Evaluate.all
  end
    def show
       @page_title = "Review setting of selected Job title"
       @review = Evaluate.find(params[:id])
    end
```

How can i solve this problem ?

```
  Is there a fix rule in cancan that model name 
    should be related to the controller name?
    Departments(controller) should have Department(model)?
    How can we implement cancan in Reviews(controller) which have Evaluate(model)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load_and_authorize_resource` method in your controller is used to load the resource into an instance variable and authorize it automatically for every action in that controller. Models and controllers can be separately authorized. In your ability.rb just use `can :manage, Evaluate` to authorize that model.

If u have a user model and have a admin boolean field in it then u can perform authorization as follows:

```
if user.admin?  
  can :manage, Evaluate   
else
  can :read, Evaluate   
end
```

Alternatively, u can authorize controller actions using authorize! method.
Answer to ur question: How can we implement cancan in Reviews(controller) which have Evaluate(model)?

```
def index
  @reviews = Evaluate.all
  authorize! :read, @reviews
end
```

Comment: any workin example for controller review and model evaluate for code in ability might helpful..

Comment: This might be fo help. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: Please format your code properly. You can use the curly braces on top of the textarea for that.

Comment: I just edit my review controller , You can look again..   This method blocks to show edit link but you can access through browser. Se we need to add  load_and_authorize_resource :message => "Unable to read this article."  in controller which did not give acess